# How to Write A Json Query In SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, ado.net, inner-join

Say I have this json in a SQL Column called `MyJson` in a table called StoreTeams

```
{
    MyTeams: [
        {
            id: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2
        },
        {
            id: 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to take all these id's and then do a inner join against another table.

```
User Table

- id <pk>
- firstName
- lastName
```

I am not sure how I would do this, I would be probably running this code via ado.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openjson()`. You don't specify the exact result you want, but the logic is:

```
select *
from mytable t
cross apply openjson(t.myjson, '$.MyTeams') with (id int '$.id') as x
inner join users u on u.id = x.id
```